# Python 3.10.6 multiprocessing pool.map pauses without any progress after the first batch / pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, boto3, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use Python boto3 on Ubuntu 22.04 to upload tens of thousands of records in excel sheet to AWS DynamoDB. So I try to use `multiprocessing` library. Here is a code snippet:

```
        shared_queue = SimpleQueue()
        m = Manager()
        value = m.Value('Q', 0)
        dictionary = m.dict()
        print(f"{len(products)} total products")
        with Pool(initializer=init_worker, initargs=(shared_queue,), processes=cpu_count()) as pool:
            func = partial(work, value, dictionary, verbose)
            _ = pool.map_async(func, products)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            print(f"Pool finished")
        print(f"Processed {value.value} records")
```

It just hangs without error and exception after about 27 records.

If I use a `noops` just doing counting:

```
def noops(sellerid, brandid, media, count, dictionary, verbose, p):
    count.value += 1
    print(f"Processed {count.value} records")
    return 0
```

The pool finishes with a count of around 4100 records.

Comment: Why not just use thread instead of process

Comment: How? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, so there is the link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

Comment: You are not getting any exceptions because you are not doing `.get` on the result object. Assign a meaningful name to `map_async` call (say, `result = ...`) and then do `result.get()`